# Why is my table view not being filled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm writing an iPhone app, but one of the table views in my storyboard isn't filling the cells in.
Here is the implementation.

```
#import "ManagerSettingsViewController.h"

@interface ManagerSettingsViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *numberOfSkillsLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderValue;

@end

@implementation ManagerSettingsViewController
@synthesize group;
@synthesize numberOfSkillsLabel;
@synthesize sliderValue;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSLog(@"Skill list count: %lu", (unsigned long)[group.skillList count]);
    for(int i = 0; i < [group.skillList count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"%@", [group.skillList objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
    int temp = (int)sliderValue.value;
    NSString *sliderVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", temp];
    [numberOfSkillsLabel setText:[sliderVal copy]];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (IBAction)backButtonListener:(id)sender {

    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)numberOfSkillsSlideListener:(id)sender {
     int temp = (int)sliderValue.value;
     NSString *sliderVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", temp];
    [numberOfSkillsLabel setText:[sliderVal copy]];
    // sliderValue.value = temp;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     NSLog(@"Skill list count: %lu", (unsigned long)[group.skillList count]);
     return [[group getSkillList] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [group.skillList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}





/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before    navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Here is the header file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Group.h"

@interface ManagerSettingsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,    UITableViewDataSource>

@property Group* group;
@end
```

To me, it looks like the method where the cells are being created is not being called, but the one returning the cell count is being called. The table view is bound.

Let me know if there are other snippets of code that you need.

Comment: Yes. If you look at the viewDidLoad method, it prints out the text values that should be going into the cell into the console. They print out the correct values, so I know the group property is not nil.

Comment: And you say that if you put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's not getting fired? Despite returning a > 0 value in `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: Yeah. I just tried it now and the breakpoint is not getting fired.

Comment: You haven't bound the DataSource in the Interface Builder then, have you?

Comment: They are bound. http://imgur.com/tubShgb

Comment: Are you returning 1 from this method? - (NSInteger)numberOfSections;

Comment: Where are you getting this method?  - (NSInteger)numberOfSections;

Comment: It is bound to the correct view. http://imgur.com/p7czZzW

Comment: Did you set up a `tableView` ? Why can't I see your property or IBOulet? Is it the `Group` class ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/p7czZzW

Comment: Would you mind uploading your project on github?

Comment: I appreciate it, but I just fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Derek: You might want to post your solution to your problem, or even delete this question, as it in it's current form does not contribute to Stack Overflow as a base of knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

It seams that you had not set delegate and dataSource for Yours tableView.